# Pyramid rendering blank page on refresh after configuring sessions

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2, session-cookies, pyramid

I am having an issue where after adding SignedCookieSessionFactory to my pyramid configuration, when I attempt to refresh the page in a browser, only a blank page is returned (both head and body tags are empty). The first time I hit that page it renders as expected. A separate session also produces a blank page. In order to get the page to render again, I must restart the server. Refresh worked fine before I added the session factory, but I would lose the state when refreshing (as expected).

Pyramid config:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    session_factory = SignedCookieSessionFactory('cossecret')
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, session_factory=session_factory)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.include('.models')
    config.include('.routes')
    config.registry.games = Games()
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

routes.py:

```
def includeme(config):
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('game', '/game/{game}')
```

view.py:

```
@view_config(route_name='game', renderer='templates/game.jinja2')
def game_view(request):
    """ Returns Game Play page based on ID"""
    if "game_id" in request.session:
        if request.matchdict['game'] != request.session["game_id"]:
            if request.matchdict['game'] in request.registry.games.games:
                request.session.invalidate()
                request.session["game_id"] = request.matchdict['game']
            else:
                raise HTTPNotFound
    else:
        if request.matchdict['game'] in request.registry.games.games:
            request.session["game_id"] = request.matchdict['game']
        else:
            raise HTTPNotFound

    response = {}
    response['game'] = request.session['game_id']
    if "player_id" in request.session:
        response['player_id'] = request.session['player_id']
    else:
        response['player_id'] = "None"
    return response
```

I am pretty new to Pyramid, so any ideas would be appreciated. Stepping through the renderer, I noticed that the renderer scanned the html headers in the template the first time, but completely skipped over them the second time and then ignores everything after the body tag. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: What renderer are you talking about when you say "the renderer scanned the html headers in the template the first time". This does not make sense to me and does not line up with anything I know about pyramid_jinja2 (and I'm a maintainer of that library).

Comment: Sorry, I was using pycharm to step through the code. I set a breakpoint at return response and stepped through unitl it hit the template. It looks like it is loading the template. The part that I was referring to is the from_code method, it appears to read each line of the template file until it hits the variables that need replacing and then returns. When it runs again when I reload the page, it only gets to the head tag and returns. I am only describing what I am seeing in pycharm. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm confident that whatever problem you're experiencing doesn't have anything to do with how your template is parsed and executed. Of course I can't see the template here nor can I reproduce your issue. The code you've pasted looks fine of course.

Comment: Michael, I found what was causing it (see answer below), but I have no idea why it produced this behavior. Any ideas why this was causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently in another of my views that is part of my API, there was this:

```
json_return = json.dumps(return_data)
response = Response     
response.content_type = 'json'      
response.body = json_return     
return Response(content_type='json', body=json_return)
```

I don't know why creating two response objects would cause this behavior, but removing the first one in favor of just using the "return" line resolved the issue.

Comment: Well the first object is a class, not an instance, and is thus affecting all response objects created from that class which would not be great.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks!